# Merge Multiple Rows in One Row Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a sql table having multiple rows in which i want to get single row from same column value in my case SKU Column.I want to merge multiple rows from same sku value into one row having all values of attribute_id and attribute_value.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure how the resulting row should look like. Especially the part "having all values of attribute_id and attribute_value". This would be done by GROUP BY, but you really need to know how the aggregation of your values should look like (usually it is e.g. MAX value, or SUM of numbers). From what I understand, you are aiming more for a GROUP_CONCAT (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are OK with having a comma-separated list of attribute IDs and values per each `sku`, then you could use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT sku,
       GROUP_CONCAT(attribute_id)    AS attribute_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(attribute_value) AS attribute_value
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY sku
```